# Ruby: recursive method

Tags: ruby, recursion

```
def reverse_append(arr, n)  
    return arr if n < 0 
    reverse_append(arr, n-1)
    arr << n
    arr
end 

reverse_append([],4) #=> [0, 1, 2, 3, 4]
```

I can't seem to understand this recursive method. It produces an array from 0 up to n.

Can someone explain this to me?

Comment: The best way to picture what a recursive function is doing is often to add some output for each iteration.  Try adding `puts arr.inspect` right above the last `arr` line in the method and run.

Comment: Where do you think it counts up?

Comment: Please be careful asking "explain it to me" questions. Wide-open, "explain all the code to me" questions are too broad and don't show any research/effort into understanding the code. "explain one particular line", after researching and explaining how the research didn't help, is much less broad and more likely to be on-topic. I didn't down vote or vote to close because it is a small code chunk.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

1. The method `reverse_append([],4)` is called
2. Since `4 >= 0`, the `return` statement does not get called.
3. The method `reverse_append([],3)` is called.
4. Since `3 >= 0`, the `return` statement does not get called.
5. The method `reverse_append([],2)` is called.
6. Since `2 >= 0`, the `return` statement does not get called.
7. The method `reverse_append([],1)` is called.
8. Since `1 >= 0`, the `return` statement does not get called.
9. The method `reverse_append([],0)` is called.
10. Since `0 >= 0`, the `return` statement does not get called.
11. The method `reverse_append([],-1)` is called.
12. **Since `-1 < 0`, the array (`[]`) is returned.**
13. We pop up one level in our call stack, to where `n = 0` and `arr = []`.
14. `arr << n` and `arr` is returned, so now `arr = [0]`.
15. We pop up one level in our call stack, to where `n = 1` and `arr = [0]`.
16. `arr << n` and `arr` is returned, so now `arr = [0, 1]`.
17. We pop up one level in our call stack, to where `n = 2` and `arr = [0, 1]`.
18. `arr << n` and `arr` is returned, so now `arr = [0, 1, 2]`.
19. We pop up one level in our call stack, to where `n = 3` and `arr = [0, 1, 2]`.
20. `arr << n` and `arr` is returned, so now `arr = [0, 1, 2, 3]`.
21. We pop up one level in our call stack, to where `n = 4` and `arr = [0, 1, 2, 3]`.
22. `arr << n` and `arr` is returned, so now `arr = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4]`.
23. Finally, the "top-level" method returns, and we have our final result.

Comment: @13aal I think the biggest conceptual difficulty that people have when learning about recursive functions for the first time is simply in going through an example, line by line, and tracking what actually happens. So yes, my answer is perhaps a little over the top; but I hope it will encourage readers to step through the code like this too, in order to understand the basic concept.

Answer (score 2):

Well step through the code with the supplied parameters. The first step is to check if n < 0 which its not. If it isn't 0 reverse append with [], 3 and appends the that array the number and then returns the array.

So it takes the array, adds 4 to it after it has gone through the step of dealing with `[], 3`, `[], 2`, `[],1` and `[], 0`. So the first call that will succeed is just returning the array when it gets below 0, next is 0 gets appended, then one, then 2, then 3 and lastly the original call with 4 gets added `arr << n`.

Answer (score 2):

There's a nice tool you can add to many editors called "[Seeing Is Believing](https://github.com/JoshCheek/seeing_is_believing)", which lets you see what is happening as code runs:

```
def reverse_append(arr, n)  
  return arr if n < 0 # => false, false, false, false, true
  reverse_append(arr, n-1) # => [], [0], [0, 1], [0, 1, 2]
  arr << n # => [0], [0, 1], [0, 1, 2], [0, 1, 2, 3]
  arr # => [0], [0, 1], [0, 1, 2], [0, 1, 2, 3]
end 

reverse_append([], 3) # => [0, 1, 2, 3]
```

However, with a name like "reverse_append" it seems like you should see a result that is descending in values:

```
def reverse_append(arr, n)  
  return arr if n < 0 # => false, false, false, false, true
  reverse_append(arr, n-1) # => [], [0], [1, 0], [2, 1, 0]
  arr.unshift n # => [0], [1, 0], [2, 1, 0], [3, 2, 1, 0]
  arr # => [0], [1, 0], [2, 1, 0], [3, 2, 1, 0]
end 

reverse_append([], 3) # => [3, 2, 1, 0]
```

In either case, there are a lot of easier ways to generate such an array without relying on recursion:

```
[*0..3] # => [0, 1, 2, 3]
(0..3).to_a # => [0, 1, 2, 3]

[*0..3].reverse # => [3, 2, 1, 0]
(0..3).to_a.reverse # => [3, 2, 1, 0]
```